# Parsing string to time value in python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I need to convert the following strings into either datetimes or strings in a different format.  My input looks like these examples:

> 196h 26m 13s
>   95h 19m
>   45m 28s

My desired string output would be (But my final goal is to convert these strings into `datetime` objects):

> 196:26:13
>   95:19:00
>   00:45:28

In Excel, it would be `[h]:mm:ss`.

Note: As you can see, hours can be higher than 24.

I have tried to parse this string with the `time.strptime()` method, but it doesn't work with hours higher than 24. I have a solution with regular expressions, but I want to know if there is a more straightforward way to do this. What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Those aren't points in time; those are durations of time.  Thus, `datetime`, `date`, and `time` are entirely the wrong types to use; the correct type is `timedelta`, which does not have a built-in string-parsing method.

Comment: I would go the re way too

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! I would stay by the good old regex way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would give you time deltas:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def to_timedelta(time_string):
    units = {'h': 'hours', 'd': 'days', 'm': 'minutes', 's': 'seconds'}
    return timedelta(**{units[x[-1]]: int(x[:-1]) for x in time_string.split()})
```

Test:

```
times = ['196h 26m 13s', '95h 19m', '45m 28s']
for t in times:
    print(to_timedelta(t))
```

Output:

```
8 days, 4:26:13
3 days, 23:19:00
0:45:28
```

[timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) takes these arguments;

> datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)

Using this mapping:

```
units = {'h': 'hours', 'd': 'days', 'm': 'minutes', 's': 'seconds'}
```

allows the short units in the string to be mapped to the corresponding names of the arguments.
Using Pythons `**` syntax, the resulting dictionary can be used as single argument that will be converted in to the matching keyword arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing we should do is use a regular expression and use timedelta instead of datetime.

```
import datetime
import re

regex = re.compile(r'((?P<hours>\d+?)h)?((?P<minutes>\d+?)m)?((?P<seconds>\d+?)s)?')

def parse_time(time_str):
    parts = regex.match(time_str)
    if not parts:
        return
    parts = parts.groupdict()
    time_params = {}
    for (name, param) in parts.items():
        if param:
            time_params[name] = int(param)
    return datetime.timedelta(**time_params)


L = ["196h 26m 13s", "95h 19m", "45m 28s"]

for l in L:
    print(parse_time(l))
```

Output:

```
8 days, 4:00:00
3 days, 23:00:00
0:45:00
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a very similar solution based on regex